# In Mailbox App on iOS, what would be triggering this zoom animation in the UI? (video included)

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

I've got a very strange bug in the Mailbox app when rendering an email, when you click on it it start to zoom out very slowly until the height of the email is shown...

There's a gif of it happening here:

http://mailrox.s3.amazonaws.com/bloggif_542959bc3de42.gif

A video here:

http://mailrox.s3.amazonaws.com/mailbox-zoom-bug.mov

And here's the HTML of the whole email, does anyone know what's triggering this slow zoom of the email?

http://jsfiddle.net/az1eryu4/

```
<body style="background: #FFFFFF; color: #000000 !important; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 17px; margin: 0px 0 0 0px; min-width: 100%; padding: 0px 0 0; width: 100%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
```

the reset of the HTML is on JSfiddle becuase there's too much to put here and it needs to be previewed.

Comment: I don't know what's causing it, but I've been having the same issue for the last week or so.

Comment: This is also happening with my mails. The problem happens both on a iPhone 5 and 6 using iOS 8.

Comment: I think I've fixed it myself, see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this is to remove the 100% body width which occur in three places: header css, inline css and the width attribute.

You may also need to remove the 100% width from the html tag and the first table tag.

As 4th of October 2014 it looks like Mailbox has been updated, not to remove this, but the zoom animation has been sped up. So if you want to stop the zooming you'll need to remove the 100% widths.